# How to Prevent a MouseMove Event from Firing After the Mouse has been Programmatically Moved

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I am trying to make a First-Person game template using WPF 3D. Whenever the mouse moves, the camera does too. I want to make a situation where the mouse is returned to the center whenever it leaves the window. I learned that you can use `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position` to change the position of the cursor. As expected, when the cursor leaves the window, it goes back to the center. However, the camera switches back to its previous position as well. I do not want the camera to move when the cursor position gets reset. Here is my code:

> `MainCamera` is the Main Camera
>
> `MainViewport` is the hosted Viewport.
>
> `Crosshair` is an ellipses that represents the crosshair.
>
> `CrosshairX` is the X location of the crosshair.
>
> `CrosshairY` is the Y location of the crosshair.
>
> `MouseX` is the X location of the mouse.
>
> `MouseY` is the Y location of the mouse.

```cs
public void Rotate(double d)
{
    // Rotate to the side a certain number of degrees
    double u = 0.05;
    double angleD = u * d;

    var m = new Matrix3D();
    m.Rotate(new Quaternion(MainCamera.UpDirection, -angleD)); // Rotate about the camera's up direction to look left/right
    MainCamera.LookDirection = m.Transform(MainCamera.LookDirection);
}

public void RotateVertical(double d)
{
    // Rotate up a certain number of degrees
    double u = 0.05;
    double angleD = u * d;

    // Cross Product gets a vector that is perpendicular to the passed in vectors (order does matter, reverse the order and the vector will point in the reverse direction)
    var cp = Vector3D.CrossProduct(MainCamera.UpDirection, MainCamera.LookDirection);
    cp.Normalize();

    var m = new Matrix3D();
    m.Rotate(new Quaternion(cp, -angleD)); // Rotate about the vector from the cross product
    MainCamera.LookDirection = m.Transform(MainCamera.LookDirection);
}

public void Move(double d)
{
    // Move forwards a certain number of steps
    double u = 0.05;
    Vector3D lookDirection = MainCamera.LookDirection;

    lookDirection.Normalize();
    MainCamera.Position = MainCamera.Position + u * lookDirection * d;
}

public void MoveSideways(double d)
{
    // Move sideways a certain number of steps
    double u = 0.05;
    Vector3D SideDirection = Vector3D.CrossProduct(MainCamera.LookDirection, MainCamera.UpDirection);
    SideDirection.Normalize();
    MainCamera.Position = MainCamera.Position + u * SideDirection * d;
}

private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Detect keypresses
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.W:
            Move(10);
            break;
        case Key.A:
            MoveSideways(-10);
            break;
        case Key.S:
            Move(-10);
            break;
        case Key.D:
            MoveSideways(10);
            break;
        }
}

private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Change the position of the crosshair if the window size changes.
    Crosshair.Margin = new Thickness(MainViewport.ActualWidth / 2, MainViewport.ActualHeight / 2, 0, 0);
    CrosshairX = MainViewport.ActualWidth / 2;
    CrosshairY = MainViewport.ActualHeight / 2;
}

private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     // Detects when the mouse moves.
    Rotate(Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow).X - MouseX);
    RotateVertical(MouseY - Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow).Y);

    MouseX = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow).X;
    MouseY = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow).Y;
}

private void Window_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Bring mouse back to center if it leaves
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point((int)CrosshairX, (int)CrosshairY);
}
```

I have noticed that adding

```cs
if (Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow).X != CrosshairX && Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow).Y != CrosshairY) {...}
```

to the `Rotate` and `RotateVertical` solves the problem, but it only works half of the time. I want a 100% efficient method.

**How can I stop the camera from moving when the cursor position is reset?**

Comment: so I don't have an answer but I would look into unbinding and rebinding events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem on my own after many, many trials. It turns out that the problem was that the `MouseX` and `MouseY` were storing the X and Y values of the window borders and were causing the camera to rotate by the angles measured from the difference of the crosshair coordinates by the window border coordinates. This caused the camera to rotate back to the center.

I solved the problem by setting the `MouseX` and `MouseY` coordinates to the crosshair coordinates so that the camera would not be spun back to center.

```cs
private void Window_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Bring mouse back to center if it leaves
    MouseX = CrosshairX;
    MouseY = CrosshairY;
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point((int)CrosshairX, (int)CrosshairY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbind your mouse move event when the mouse leaves, then rebind after reset.

Assuming your window is bound to the event I will use `this`. If something else is bound change `this` to your control's `Name`.

```
private void Window_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Unbind the event
    this -= Window_MouseMove;

    // Bring mouse back to center if it leaves
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point((int)CrosshairX, (int)CrosshairY);

    //Rebind the event
    this += Window_MouseMove;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, unbinding events in this case does not work. I believe that actual binding/unbinding operations take place after the central window has returned back to its standard "wait" mode (i.e. not executing code). The request to bind/unbind operations is placed on the Message Queue which is executed after all other operations have completed (instead of `Unbind -> MoveCursor -> Rebind` it goes `MoveCursor -> Unbind -> Rebind`). I'm not entirely sure if that explanation is correct, as I am basing it off my knowledge gained from experimenting with the lower-level C/C++ Window libraries.